# url getting doubled when opening a link from the home page.(django)

Tags: django

On clicking the 2nd item in the list it opens the events.html page but the url shows: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/events/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/events

Home page code:

```
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'events' %}">EVENTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">REGISTERED TEAMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
     path('hackathon_register/',views.hackathon_register,name='hackathon_register'),
     path('events/',views.events,name='events')
]
```

views.py

```
def events(request):
    return render(request,'testapp/events.html',{})
```

Answer (score 0):

From here, it seems that your code in urls.py of project is:

```
.......

urlpatterns = [
     ....
     path('events/', include("app.urls")),

]
```

So correct this mistake either by changing project.urls or app.urls.

Comment: No that's the urls.py of my app

Comment: The project one is the same as yours.

Comment: Basically when you type a url, django looks in project's urls.py , in this it matches "events/" and further include() takes it to app.urls , here it again matches "events/", and gives it a name="events/". Therefore name = "events" has stored http://localhost/events/events. Therefore changing anyone of these urls.py will do you good.

Comment: have you got it?

Comment: yeah.i put it as /events so it comes under the localhost as localhost/events.

Comment: great. mark it as correct answer and upvote it bro.